# gpg does not require passphrase to decrypt

Tags: decryption, passphrase

Suddenly the behaviour of gpg has changed and my world crumbles.

I have several keys, all but one for testing purposes.  The one is my personal key.  Up to now I have been able to encrypt with this key, and I seem to remember that I had to type my passphrase to encrypt.  Now suddenly I don't.  But what is more frightening, I can double click the encrypted file and it will decrypt without asking for my passphrase.

I have googled on this, and found several suggestions, none of which works.  How do I force gpg to ask for my passphrase before it decrypts a file?  And how do I make sure that it encrypts with the right key.  I use -r  but it appears that the key doing the encryption is not my own key even if  is the name of my personal key.  I can accept that it is the recipients key which matters in encryption, but I would like my personal identity to be involved, and not the first key in the keyring.

Comment: If you are just encrypting, your private key is not needed, so it doesn't make sense to need to unlock it. If you are encrypting _and_ signing, or just signing, then you will need the key and passphrase.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, multith3at3d.  I realise that it is the recipient's key which should be used to encrypt.  What concerns me a lot more is that I can double-click on the .gpg file and a decrypted copy is created without my needing to enter my passphrase.  I want to keep certain files on my hard disk which are encrypted, but which I can decrypt as necessary, but I don't want them decrypted simply by a double click.

Comment: What OS is this, and what key software is in use? I.e. do you have a key manager, like Gnome's?

Comment: I'm using gpg installed via GPG Suite on a Mac running High Sierra, although I seek to encrypt the files in a terminal window with gig -e -r "James Wilde" <file-to-be-encrypted>.  When the file has been encrypted, double-clicking on it decrypts it.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to `gpg-agent` temporarily caching your password. You can [easily disable caching](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193595/277264).